# x11vnc on lubuntu 19.10

Tags: linux, администрирование, vnc

Пожалуйста, подскажите, почему у меня не получается получить доступ к экрану до входа пользователя в систему?

**Ошибка**

> -auth guess: failed for display=':0'

**Запуск**

```
x11vnc -auth guess -rfbfauth [path]
```

Пробовал запускать сценарий как службу, запускать sh  скрипт через crontab - одно и тоже. Если же в -auth указать данные из сессии пользователя и войти в систему - все работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @user7860670 Я запустил систему, вижу экран блокировки, значит существует?

Comment: `x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess` - попробуй это.

Comment: @donRumata Пробовал тысячу раз. И мы же получаем ошибку о том, что как раз к этому дисплею не можем получить доступ

Comment: Ну ты делал же `sudo -i`, а потом мою строку?

Comment: @donRumata Не помогло. Может есть аналог с которым у меня не будет таких проблем? + мне ещё будет нужен доступ к виртуальному рабочему столу, хотел ставить другой VNC сервер вместе с x11vnc

Comment: Хз, у меня отлично пашет через vpn до работы. Цепляюсь к xubuntu 16.04. Попробуй тогда `xrdp`. Или тебе надо смотреть за экраном пользователя?

Comment: @donRumata Мне нужно и смотреть, и подключатся отдельно

Comment: Для "отдельно" - `xrdp` и `x2go`.

Comment: @donRumata Это бесплатно? Предполагается коммерческое использование

Comment: @donRumata Подскажите пожалуйста, 1. как мне восстановить grub после восстановления копии диска акронисом на другой машине? 2. Я делал копию системы на uefi, как мне теперь её восстановить на машину которая не поддерживает uefi? Восстановить на ту, которая поддерживает, а потом как-то сделать копию, которую я смогу на такой машине восстановить?

Comment: Оффтоп. Задай как новый вопрос.

Comment: `Это бесплатно?` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xrdp, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X2Go